# Python ijson - parse error: trailing garbage // bz2.decompress()

Tags: python, twitter, error-handling, bz2, ijson

I have come across an error while parsing json with ijson.

Background:
I have a series(approx - 1000) of large files of twitter data that are compressed in a '.bz2' format. I need to get elements from the file into a `pd.DataFrame` for further analysis. I have identified the keys I need to get. I am cautious putting twitter data up.

Attempt:
I have managed to decompress the files using `bz2.decompress` with the following code:

```
## Code in loop specific for decompressing and parsing - 

with open(file, 'rb') as source:
                # Decompress the file
                json_r = bz2.decompress(source.read())
                json_decom =  json_r.decode('utf-8') # decompresses one file at a time rather than a stream
                
                # Parse the JSON with ijson 
                parser = ijson.parse(json_decom)
                for prefix, event, value in parser:
                    # Print selected items as part of testing
                    if prefix=="created_at":
                        print(value)
                    if prefix=="text":
                        print(value)
                    if prefix=="user.id_str":
                        print(value)
```

This gives the following error:

```
IncompleteJSONError: parse error: trailing garbage
          estamp_ms":"1609466366680"}  {"created_at":"Fri Jan 01 01:59
                     (right here) ------^
```

Two things:

- Is my decompression method correct and giving the right type of file for ijson to parse (ijson takes both bytes and str)?
- Is is a JSON error? // If it is a JSON error is it possible to develop some kind of error handler to move to the next file - if so any suggestion would be appreciated?

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you, James

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To directly answer your two questions:

- The decompression method is correct in the sense that it yields JSON data that you then feed to `ijson`. As you point out, `ijson` works both with `str` and `bytes` inputs (although the latter is preferred); if you were giving `ijson` some non-JSON input you wouldn't see an error showing JSON data in it.
- This is a very common error that is described [in ijson's FAQ](https://github.com/ICRAR/ijson#id6). It basically means your JSON document has more than one top-level value, which is not standard JSON, but is supported by ijson by using the `multiple_values` option (see docs for details).

About the code as a whole: while it's working correctly, it could be improved on: the whole point of using `ijson` is that you can avoid loading the full JSON contents in memory. The code you posted doesn't use this to its advantage though: it first opens the bz-compressed file, reads it as a whole, decompresses *that* as a whole, (unnecessarily) decodes *that* as a whole, and then gives the decoded data as input to `ijson`. If your input file is small, and the decompressed data is also small you won't see any impact, but if your files are big then you'll definitely start noticing it.

A better approach is to stream the data through all the operations so that everything happens incrementally: decompression, no decoding and JSON parsing. Something along the lines of:

```py
with bz2.BZ2File(filename, mode='r') as f:
    for prefix, event, value in ijson.parse(f):
        # ...
```

As the cherry on the cake, if you want to build a DataFrame from that you can use DataFrame's [data argument](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html#pandas.DataFrame) to build the DataFrame directly with the results from the above. `data` can be an iterable, so you can, for example, make the code above a generator and use it as `data`. Again, something along the lines of:

```py
def json_input():
   with bz2.BZ2File(filename, mode='r') as f:
       for prefix, event, value in ijson.parse(f):
           # yield your results

df = pandas.DataFrame(data=json_input())
```